# Weighted F-test in R

Tags: r, variance

I'm wondering how to perform a weighted F-test in R? I am looking for a weighted version of this:

```r
x <- rnorm(120)
y  <- rnorm(120)
var.test(x, y)
```

I have used [this function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/weights/versions/1.0/topics/wtd.t.test) for a weighted t-test but I'm struggling to find an equivalent for the F-test.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The package `wle` seems to provide a function `wle.var.test` which performs a weighted F-test *"to compare the variances of two samples from normal populations. The WF-test is based on weighted likelihood."*

Unfortunately `wle` has been removed from CRAN because *"check problems were not corrected despite reminders"*. Fortunately, we can still install the package through the GH read-only mirror

```r
devtools::install_github("https://github.com/cran/wle")
```

Note that compiling `wle` from source requires `gfortran` (which is part of the `gcc` package).

After installation we can do the following:

```r
library(wle)
set.seed(2020)
x <- rnorm(120)
y <- rnorm(120)
wle.var.test(wle.normal(x, group = 5), wle.normal(y, group = 5))
#
#   WF test to compare two variances
#
#data:  wle.normal(x, group = 5) and wle.normal(y, group = 5)
#WF = 0.95235, num df = 114.11, denom df = 113.65, p-value = 0.7948
#alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
#95 percent confidence interval:
# 0.6583161 1.3775135
#sample estimates:
#ratio of variances
#         0.9523465
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I also found this function but I'm not sure it is quite what I need. The reason being that I can't see how you can pass the weights to this function. The T-test function that I'm looking an alternative for has weights as an input argument but I'm not seeing this option for `wle.var.test`

Comment: @user3413926 I see; I'm not familiar with `wle.var.test`; personally I'd stay away from any weighted hypothesis test and use a (potentially Bayesian) model to estimate (differences in the) means and variances of the underlying distributions. Sorry, can't help.